# C3p0 - APPARENT DEADLOCK on MSSQL, but not PostgreSQL or MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, deadlock, c3p0

We are getting exceptions like this

```
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@5b7a7896 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
Managed Threads: 3
Active Threads: 3
Active Tasks: 
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@55bc5e2a (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@41ca435f (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StatementCloseTask@460d33b7 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
Pending Tasks:
```

when load testing our application on **MSSQL 2008 R2 (jTDS or official MS JDBC doesn't matter)**. We never get this exception when running the same tests against **PostgreSQL** or **MySQL**.

We don't just want to increase the number of helper threads for c3p0 (which solves the problem, but how long?). We want to know what's the problem as it is workings with other DBMS'.

The applications behaves like:

- Send X requests
- Wait for a while -> DEADLOCK
- Send X requests
- Wait for a while -> DEADLOCK

Does anyone know or has an idea why we have this behavior with MSSQL?

Thanks, Adrian

(Btw. BoneCP works without any problem too.)

Comment: What is this utility and why does it report "apparent deadlock" rather than actual deadlock? SQL Server will detect actual deadlocks. You can trace the deadlock graph to then diagnose why it occurs.

Comment: Hi Martin, SQL Server itself doesn't get deadlocks. It seems to be just c3p0 (a connection pooling lib for Java) assumes there was a deadlock.

Comment: Adrian -- can you please clarify whether using BoneCP avoided the problem?

Comment: @tgdavies Yes, BoneCP avoids the problem, but I don't know why, because C3P0 is (sadly) set for us we are not digging deeper into other pooling libs . I think BoneCP is technically more advanced and maybe uses a better or more optimistic standard configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server has a much more restrictive locking strategy compared to PostgreSQL or InnoDB.

Especially it will block SELECTs on rows (tables?) that are updated from a different connection/transaction (in the default installation).

You should make sure that you are not selecting the same rows in one session that are being updated from another.

If you can't change the sequence of your code, you might get away with using "dirty reads" in SQL Server.

If I remember that correctly, this is accomplished by adding `WITH NOLOCK` to the SELECT statements (but I'm not entirely sure)

**Edit**
A different possibility (if you are on SQL Server 2005 or later) would be to use the new "snapshot isolation" to avoid blocking selects.

Comment: SQL Server also has snapshot isolation.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I know. That's why I said "default installation". But you have a point there: switching to snapshot isolation might also solve that problem.

Comment: You didn't say "default installation". Maybe you thought it!